# Filter Events which has some specific status

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to query my database to fetch only rows which has the 'CONFIRMED' status, but the status is saved on the Log table, not on events, where i need to execute the query. The `logs` table store all the surgery status, and the current status of the surgery with ID 1 is the last row inserted with `surgery_id` 1. How can i get all events whose surgery has the status `CONFIRMED`?

This is my database structure:

```
 Surgery           Events              Log
    id               id                id
patient_id       surgery_id         surgery_id
                                    status_id
```

I'm using laravel v5.7.28, with postgresql database.

On `surgery` model:

```php
public function status()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Cirurgia_log::class)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

if i use the following code, instead of the first one, i can get the last status successfully:

```php
public function status()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Log::class)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
}
```

But, with this one, i can't use with the `whereHas` function.

The `surgery` relation is defined on `Events` model:

```
public function surgery()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Surgery::class, 'surgery_id');
}
```

I tried using the code below, but, with this one, if the surgery was CONFIRMED but now is CANCELED, the event corresponding to that surgery will also be returned, once that surgery has already been confirmed sometime.

```php
Events::whereHas('surgery.status', function ($query){
    $query->where('status_id', env('CONFIRMED'));
})->get();
```

Summing up, i need to fetch only events where the surgery related to that event has the CONFIRMED status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following code:

```php
public function scopeConfirmedMaterials()
{
    return $this->whereHas('surgery.latestStatus', function ($query){
        $query->where('status_id', env('CONFIRMED'));
    })->get()
        ->filter(function ($event){
            return $event->surgery
                ->latestStatus
                ->status_id == env('CONFIRMED');
        });
}
```

The `surgery` relation on Event model:

```php
public function surgery()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Surgery::class);
}
```

The `latestStatus` relation, on Surgery model:

```php
public function latestStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Log::class)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

`EventController`:

```php
public function getEvent(){
    return response()->json(
        'data' => Events::confirmedMaterials();
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply swap `HasMany` with `HasOne`:

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Log::class)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

The issue with `status` as a word is that it's ambiguous. It's the same for singular and plural, which makes it hard to determine whether we are talking about one or many. So I'd probably go for `latestStatus()` with `HasOne` and for `status()` with `HasMany` to cover both.

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Log::class)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}

public function latestStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Log::class)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

Comment: I replace my function with yours, using `hasOne`, but it still returning events whose the current status is not CONFIRMED. Same problem

Comment: Can you please add the generated SQL query to your question? If you don't use a debugging tool that shows you the executed SQL queries, you can enable the SQL query log right before the query with `\DB::enableQueryLog()` and dump the query log with `\var_dump(DB::getQueryLog())` after the query has been executed.

Comment: Sure. this is the generated script:


array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(341) "select * from "events" where exists (select * from "surgeries" where "events"."surgery_id" = "surgeries"."id" and exists (select * from "logs" where "surgeries"."id" = "logs"."surgery_id" and "status_id" = ? and "logs"."deleted_at" is null) and "surgeries"."deleted_at" is null) and "events"."deleted_at" is null" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "17" } ["time"]=> float(22.49)

Comment: Hm, you really sure you have the same code I suggested? I miss the `order by` entirely.

Comment: Yeah, i have the same `latestStatus` function that you suggested.